# How to show the day in which the most connections conducted in each month in Qlik sense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

My data is about connections in 2019. It should show the day in which maximum connections conducted in each month.

It should be like that:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 01.03.2019 | 45 |
| Feb | 02.05.2019 | 43 |

But i was able to achieve:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 01.03.2019 | 752 |
| Feb | 02.05.2019 | 742 |

This so far. It shows total number of connections in that month instead of that day.

I will be grateful if somebody helps me solve this. Thanks ahead.

Comment: Wnat is the expression/measure code?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how exactly you want the end result to look, you can use a combination of the following functions and expressions:

- [`Aggr()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/aggr.htm)
- [`Max()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/BasicAggregationFunctions/max.htm)
- [`Only()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/BasicAggregationFunctions/only.htm)
- [`Concat()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/StringAggregationFunctions/concat.htm)
- [`Total` qualifier](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/define-aggregation-scope.htm)
- [Set analysis](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm)

Here's what we can achieve using those functions:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense table showing desired result]

To create the field **[Connection Month]**, we simply use the expression `Month([Connection Date])` in the Data Load Editor when creating the new field, though it may be wise to use something like `MonthName([Connection Date])` instead in case we ever need to view multiple years at the same time.

Then, to create the aggregation expressions in a table chart, we can first create the **[Dates with Monthly Max]** field by using the following expression:

```
=Concat(
  Aggr(
    Only(
          {<[Connection Date] = {"=Aggr(Max(total <[Connection Month]> Aggr(Count([Connection ID]), [Connection Date])) = Sum(Aggr(Count([Connection ID]), [Connection Date])), [Connection Month], [Connection Date])"}>}
          [Connection Date]
      )
    , [Connection Date]
), ', ')
```

Let's break that down:

```
{<[Connection Date] = {"=Aggr(Max(total <[Connection Month]> Aggr(Count([Connection ID]), [Connection Date])) = Sum(Aggr(Count([Connection ID]), [Connection Date])), [Connection Month], [Connection Date])"}>}
```

Above is the set expression that we use to select only the **[Connection Dates]** where the count of **[Connection ID]** was the `Max()` for that **[Connection Month]**.

```
=Concat(
  ...
, ', ')
```

The above `Concat()` function will make a comma list of dates if multiple dates each have the `Max()` count of **[Connection ID]** for that **[Connection Month]**.

Finally, we use the following expression to create the **[Monthly Connection Max]** field:

```
=Max(total <[Connection Month]> Aggr(Count([Connection ID]), [Connection Date]))
```